# sphinx autodoc help

Tags: django, python-sphinx

Trying to use autdoc extension of sphinx but its not working. i kept "docs" folder in djano project folder. its not generating docs for my module.  Also i am not sure how does auto-todo works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your `index.rst` file we can only guess, and my guess would be missing something like this:

```
.. automodule:: myproject.myapp
    :members:
```

Where of course you replace `myproject` and `myapp` with your apps.

You can also try using this very new project http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sphinx-autodoc/0.0 which is so new it's at version 0.0!

Here are some blog posts discussing how to use autodoc:

http://yml-blog.blogspot.com/2009/06/sphinx-autodoc-and-django-app.html

http://www.toast38coza.com/incomplete-thoughts/setting-up-sphinx-documenter-with-a-django-project-a-quickstart-tutorial